# load bearing wall above closet?

Tags: load-bearing, closet, demolition

***EDITED*** after demolition, I went back into the attach to pinpoint the exact ceiling 2x4 (I can see between the drywall gaps to the bedroom below). Now I have more reason to believe it's load bearing...

1956 home. Wife wanted a to remove this closet with inaccessible corners and build a custom closet. I'm a DIYer who does excessive research to prepare, still gets in too deep, then scrambles but ultimately chooses the "proper" solutions without cutting corners.

First off, I understand that the only way to determine if a wall is load bearing is to look in the attic above (to see if joists cross perpendicular to the wall) and the crawlspace below (to see if there are support columns). I checked both and it didn't appear to be load bearing -- but perhaps I was wrong.

I demo'd the wall and found a thick header (11"H x 3.5"W x 64.5"L), and then standard framing on either side (vertical studs spaced 14", horizontal at 48").

**Question #1**: is this a load bearing wall, or a removable closet header?

Reasons for thinking it is not load bearing:

- The same wall aligns with the doors of the second bedroom, 2 hallway closets and a 4' wide inset cabinet (no stud supports here), before ending at the living room, and there are no electricals, plumbing or other utilities running through this line. I thought that *might* suggest it is a curtain wall. I figured the load bearing wall would more likely be located at the back of the closet which aligns with the backs of all the hallway closets (i.e. a more continuous wall) and has electricals (see photos).
- The header is floating above the vertical supports, and one support is wiggly (see photo). I would think the header would need to rest on those supports to hold any weight from above?
- The encountered the same thick header above the hallway bathroom door which is opposite from the hallway closet doors/cabinets. Perhaps this was just the standard for all openings (doors, windows) back in the day, or perhaps both walls are load bearing.

Reasons for thinking it is load bearing:

- **EDITED**: In the 1/2'-inch space between the header and ceiling drywall, there are a set of what appear to be attic joists that meet on the "ceiling 2x4" -- one 2x4 going left, and one larger (2x6?) going right.
- **EDITED** (new info) the same ceiling 2x4 that the 2x4 and 2x6 meet at also appears to support a beam from the angle roof.
- My inner critic saying of course I was wrong.

**Question #2**: If it is load-bearing, what are my options?

We would be fine with installing a wider header to eliminate the side walls, and I understand I may need a thicker header to do so, help from a contractor, and pull permits.
Any solution forward is a good one. My main concern is that my only option is to rebuild the same closet!
[image: wall before demo]
[image: after demo]
[image: wall aligns with door to second bedroom]
[image: wall aligns with all other hallway doors and cabinets]
[image: header floating above vertical supports on both sides]
[image: 2x4s running perpendicular to, and meeting at, header and ceiling 2x4.]
[image: from attic, looking down between gaps in ceiling drywall to the bedroom. The beam going from top to bottom is the bedroom ceiling 2x4. 2x4s and 2x6s (?) meet in pairs at the ceiling 2x4. The 2x4 with the three nails at the bottom is an angled roof support beam shown in the next photo]
[image: angled roof support beam attached to bedroom ceiling 2x4?]

Comment: Do you have access to the attic? I wouldn't think it's loadbearing but the perpendicular 2x4's are interesting.

Comment: It would be an odd place for a load bearing wall unless there was extra weight placed above it.  Sometimes it is just easier to place a big board there instead of making a few small/cripple studs to hold drywall.  Load bearing walls need to be supported from the basement/bottom of the house.

Comment: As you started the header is not even sitting on the jack stud on the right side.  Add no support below and i believe this is common 1956 framing .  Non load bearing.

Comment: After I removed the drywall to expose a gap between the frame and ceiling drywall, I went back to the attic to see exactly which wall I’m talking about… and sure enough, there are rows of 2x4s and a 2x6 meeting side-by-side above the header 2x4. That same header 2x4 is also a support for a beam extending from the roof. 

So, load bearing? This is why I'm confused! 
I'll add more photos of this.

Comment: I made edits ("EDITS") and added two photos. I thought it was non-load bearing for the reasons you all based your answers on... but now I'm extra convinced it is load bearing because of the joists meeting & the roof support. Apologies for the runaround!
I still don't know why the header wouldn't be touching the studs below, and thought this may just be a 1950s framing technique, but I'm having a hard time seeing how it isn't load-bearing given the new information...
Maybe the header and jack studs are not functioning as support, but the rest of wall (i.e. studs L & R) is still load bearing?